# Apply JavaScript to the layout in React after route is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reactjs

Using Meteor 1.4, Flow Router, and React, I need to execute some JavaScript code to initialize the layout. Currently, I have this

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'Home',
  action() {
    mount(MainLayout, {
      content: <div>Home</div>
    });
  }
});
```

And I need to execute this

```
$(function () {
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

on the Layout HTML. This piece of code should be executed every time `MainLayout` is being rendered, and the same layout will be used in other routes (obviously!).

Where should I put the layout initialisation code?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI both **initialize** and **initialise** are acceptable english grammar, BTW.

Comment: **Really!**..thank you for info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your component's `componentDidMount` function:

```
class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();  
  }
}
```

...unless you want to re-run those on updates (like when props including children change):

```
class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.isMounted = true; 
    this.initialiseJQueryWidgets();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.isMounted) // In case you're doing server-side rendering
      this.initialiseJQueryWidgets();
  }

  initialiseJQueryWidgets() {
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();  
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! My layout was a single `({content}) => ( <div>foo</div> )`. I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately stateless functional components don't have any rendering lifecycle hooks.

Comment: I didn't know I could use a `Component` as layout. Excellent!